# Trouble setting UIImageView image from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

The first view controller calls this method that sends the image

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

...
[wallPostCreateViewController viewDidLoad];

  [wallPostCreateViewController selectImage:wallPostCreateViewController.myImage];

NSLog(@"FROM PAWWallViewController %@",wallPostCreateViewController.myImage); //Image is there


}
```

I receive the image in the second view controller but it fails to put the image into its UIImageView.

```
- (void)selectImage:(UIImage *)img
{

if (self.condition)
{
    NSLog(@"View loaded!"); //is loaded
    [self selectImageNow:img];
    self.condition = NO;
}
else
    NSLog(@"View did NOT load!");


}
- (void)selectImageNow: (UIImage *)img
{

    NSLog(@"Image passed  %@", img); // This is the UIImage being passed.

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    self.imageView.image = img;

    NSLog(@"Image in view  %@", self.imageView.image); //has value
    NSLog(@"Imageview  %@", self.imageView); //has value


 }
```

UPDATED:

**The code above is updated now. All of the logs now have values but I still see no image or image view when I run the app**

Comment: What about `self.imageView`? Isn't it nil?

Comment: self.imageView is nil yes

Comment: That's why it's not shown. You have to allocate the imageView first.

Comment: ohhh okay so there is no imageView at all. There must be another problem in my code then right?

Comment: thanks so much! don't know how I didn't see this before

Comment: When you instantiate the `wallPostCreateViewController`, you can initialize the imageView.

Comment: I initialized the imageView but it's still not working. See the above code to see the current state its in. @trick14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems like your imgView is nil. So make sure that your method should not get called, before your view has been loaded.

Comment: How would I do that exactly? I've tried  initializing ImageView and I now get a value for ImageView but it doesn't appear on my screen. I  updated the code above.

Comment: It is called when UIButton is tapped

Comment: It is a different view controller than where the actual method selectImage is. So the button essentially links the two view controllers.

Comment: Just updated code. I called viewdidLoad before I called selectImage but I still get the same results as before :/

Comment: It is an outlet. my imageView is not nil but it still doesn't show up on my view controller. How should I be allocating it. Example code if you can please.

Comment: Remove this line self.imageView.image = img; and check??

Comment: I think the UIImageView is the incorrect frame size. Output shows that it is (0 0; 640 640)  when my actual frame size for UIImageView needs to be (60 227; 200 200). Still trying to fix this issue however. Usually imagePickerController handles this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Send `UIImage object` from one to another `ViewController` then assign that `UIImage` to `UIImageView`in `ViewWillAppear` OR `ViewDidLoad` method of `SecondController`.

Comment: I made sure the view was loaded first and I now get a value for everything but I can't see the imageView in my actual app. Am I allocation correctly? see the above code for the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the imageView of first view controller in prepareForSegue method that is in the second view controller, where you will have your destination to be the first view controller, do something like this in the second view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"firstVwCtrl"]){

    FirstViewController *frstVwCtrl = [segue destinationViewController];
    [frstVwCtrl setImgGot:_photoView.image];

          }  }
```